# Access denied errors in windows server 2008 for system administrator

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I've a HP Pavilion DV4 with windows Server 2008 R2 enterprise. My system is connected to a domain. I login using my domain account. I am the administrator for the local machine. But I'm getting access denied everywhere (file system, running commands, using visual studio..literally everywhere..) in my machine. What could be the problem? Any ideas?

Please tell me if you need more information as I'm just a developer with less knowledge in system administration.

Comment: Are you logging in to the domain or logging in locally?

Comment: I've mentioned that I login using my domain account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UAC is causing this. When in a domain auto elevation only works if you are either The Administrator (ie using that specific account, not just a member of Local Administrators) or you are a member of Domain Admins. There are ways around this but if all you need to do are local actions then selecting Run As Administrator should solve your immediate issues.

There is a complete explanation in [this Technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772207%28WS.10%29.aspx), including some options on how to modify the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I detached my lap from the domain couple of days ago and reattached it. That was the problem. I again detached it and reattached to the domain today and it solved all the issues.

Comment: But I'm marking this as answer as most of the articles/forum posts suggest the same thing.

Comment: I suspect that there is a GPO in the domain that changes the auto-elevation behavior that hadn't applied to your system originally for some reason. Removing and re-adding it might have given it enough of a kick to resolve it, or it might just have needed a reboot or two to take effect.